# Update Manager unable to get update

Tags: updates

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I fix a 404 Error using a PPA?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/65911/how-can-i-fix-a-404-error-using-a-ppa)

When I try to get updates, update manager shows that message

[image: image of the warning]

Comment: Clear your question please.

Comment: You are trying to show us a screenshot, but instead of uploading it, you give us a link to a file on your local hard disk (but we cannot see it). Edit your original message, click on "img", when prompted, choose the screenshot file from your disk and upload it.

Comment: [1]: http://i.stack.imgur.com/XLXzp.png